# .NET Web Service Object need to dispose

Tags: .net

I have developed .net web service application, in this whether i need to dispose all objects before leaving the method or it will automatically handle by garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that implement `IDisposable` you need to dispose. Any other object will be collected automatically.

The best way to dispose:

```
using (var item = new ADisposableClass())
{
   // Use the item here
}
// item will be disposed even if there was an error since it is inside "using"
```

Answer (score 0):

An object that implements `IDisposable` is telling you to explicitly call its `Dispose` method when you are done with it. This will be because it consumes resources that should only be held for the minimum amount of time possible.

The `Dispose` call frees up any resources used by the object. In typical implementations of the `Dispose` method, the garbage collector will call an overload of this method when it finalises the object, which will deal with any unmanaged resources such as file handles. But managed resources will typically not be released at this point; instead they will wait for the garbage collector to clean them up too.

So you should always, not just in a web service method, dispose such an object when you are finished with it. `using` blocks are the easiest way to do this.